# Динамическое изменение запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица с группами, предметами, и количеством часов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате выполнения алгоритма, должно получится следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видно из иллюстрации у меня получилось это реализовать. НО! Реализация прошла только по одному условию

```
$bd = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE profile='Менеджмент' AND discipline='Информатика'");


while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($bd)) {
            $res = $myrow['type'];
            if ($res == 'Лекция') {
                $lec = $lec + $myrow['count_hours'];
                $countgroup++;
                $countstudents = $countstudents + $myrow['count_students'];
            }

            if ($res == 'Семинар') {
            $seminar = $seminar + $myrow['count_hours'];
            }

            if ($res == 'Лабораторная') {
                $lab = $lab + $myrow['count_hours'];
                $countpodgroup++;
            }

            $discipline = $myrow['discipline'];
            $profile = $myrow['profile'];
            $course_semestr = $myrow['course_semestr'];

            }
$bde = mysql_query("UPDATE result SET id='$id', discipline='$discipline', profile='$profile', course_semestr='$course_semestr', count_students='$countstudents', count_group='$countgroup', count_podgroup='$countpodgroup', lectures='$lec',seminar='$seminar',lab='$lab'");
```

В таблице же помимо МЕНЕДЖМЕНТА, будут другие значения(Психология, Информатика и т.д.) Поэтому нужно написать алгоритм так, чтоб он разделял эти значения, а не складывал их вместе. Я так понимаю что нужно все это обернуть в **цикл?**

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, что вы пробовали и что у вас не получилось? Насколько я понимаю, это учебное задание?

Comment: Вовсе нет. Это задание на самом деле с большим количеством полей, и вычислений. Мне просто нужно понять принцип работы, и применить его в своем проекте. Для того чтобы не расписывать все поля которые имеются в моем проекте, я решил не впутывать вас в свои определения, а привести это все на простом наглядном примере

Comment: В таком случае, стоит переформулировать условие и *заголовок* так, чтобы читающим было проще разобраться в задаче. Добавьте краткое текстовое описание в вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, секунду

Answer (score 1):

Это называется пивот, описание принципа [здесь](http://easy4web.ru/?p=1099) 
Если набор предметов динамический, то обсуждение возможных вариантов решения [тут](http://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4304).

Comment: Не знал что это называется "пивот". Нужно будет почитать. Спасибо